# How to prove $\|\bf x\|^{\it p}_{\it p}$ can be a convex function on $ \mathbb R^n $

Tags: convex-analysis

How to show that $ \|\mathbf{x}\|^p_p $ can be a convex function on $ \mathbb R^n $ for $ p>1 $,  
where $ \displaystyle \|\mathbf{x}\|^p_p = \sum_{i=0}^n |\mathcal{x_i}|^p $ is the *p*th power of the $ l_{p} $-norm of the vector $ \mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n $.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convexity of distance function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705645/convexity-of-distance-function?rq=1)

Answer (score 4):

In fact, you have strict convexity for $1 < p < \infty$. See proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/80145/168758), e.g.

Comment: Note that the linked answer is for deriving the convexity of $\|x\|_p$ not $\|x\|_p^p$. You can however combind it with this answer: [Composition of convex and power function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849573/composition-of-convex-and-power-function)

Comment: Good point. I overlooked it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be that function. Let $\mathbf x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n$ be a point of $\mathbb R^n$. For all $i\neq j$ in $\{1,\dots,n\}$, we have
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(\mathbf x) = 0
$$
(since the derivative w.r.t. to $x_j$ exists because $p>1$, is $px_j|x_j|^{p-2}$).

For $i=j$ however we have
$$
\frac{\partial^2 f}{{\partial x_i}^2}(\mathbf x) = p|x_i|^{p-2} + p(p-2)x_i^2|x_i|^{p-4} =
 p|x_i|^{p-2}(1+p-2) = p(p-1)|x_i|^{p-2} \geq 0.
$$

Thus $f$'s Hessian matrix $\nabla^2f$ at any point $\mathbf x$ is diagonal with nonnegative eigenvalues thus positive semidefinite, which means $f$ is convex.